Does the echo command in Bash shell ever write anything to stderr without an explicit redirect of the output?
Plenty of other commands/binaries would (for example wc --wrong-flag) but is echo one of them?
Context: I am maintaining somebody else's Bash script, looking at the following section of it (slightly redacted for security):
log_file_path="logs/some_prefix_redacted.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S).log"
echo "Running Step 1 - Deleting files from S3 recursively" >> "${log_file_path}" 2>&1
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://s3_path_redacted >> "${log_file_path}" 2>&1
step_1_exit_code="${?}"
echo "Step 1 - Deleting files from S3 recursively finished with exit code ${step_1_exit_code}." >> "${log_file_path}" 2>&1

I am wondering if I need these: 2>&1 at the end of the echo commands. They pipe stderr to stdout before piping stdout to a log file, and in general this is what we do want in this case - we do not want to lose any relevant info. However, in the case of the echo command specifically, is it necessary? Would the echo command ever send something to stderr without an explicit redirect? It looks like, if I were to try to redirect echo's stdout and stderr to the same file that the current user does not have permissions for, then the error will be just dumped into the regular stderr. In any case, it seems that trying to redirect stderr to stdout to a file when using echo command is useless.
Hopefully not, hopefully echo is a ... "trusted primitive building block" for the lack of better words.
Our goal is to a) retain as much relevant info as possible for the purposes of debugging, and b) keep the code clean, not write any dead or useless code.

What I tried:
I can cause echo to output some text to stderr if I redirect either stdout or stderr to a file that I do not have write permissions for, but I am still not sure if it is possible to get echo to output something to stderr without an explicit redirect.

I suppose this is a separate question, but what if the echo command itself fails? For example, for some reason there are insufficient permissions to create or write to the log file.
$ echo "This won't work" > /root/not_allowed 2>&1
bash: /root/not_allowed: Permission denied
$ echo "${?}"
1
# Huh? I was not even trying to write anything to stderr, but it still failed?
$ echo "Will this work?" 2>/root/not_allowed
bash: /root/not_allowed: Permission denied

I want some indication that the script failed. I suppose I should try writing something to the log file at the very beginning via echo, and if that command fails, judging by the exit code, attempt to send an email or a Slack notification about the error.
One thought is to ditch Bash entirely and to write everything in Python because it has rich Exceptions, but ... there are fewer guarantees that Python will start successfully. Maybe I am using the wrong version of it, maybe it is missing the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH value. In that sense, bash is virtually guaranteed to exist on almost any mainstream Linux OS, so it is more reliable, but it's not as good at error checking or managing complexity than a language like Python.

What do you want to happen exactly? If you try to write errors to a file you don't have permissions for they're still going to go somewhere. Where do you want it to go?

The permission error happens in bash when it tries to open the output file, it never executes echo itself. You could get an error from echo if the disk is full when it tries to write.

@tjm3772 Thank for the comment 1) I want a more reliable script that is not overly complex. 2) I am wondering if I need 2>&1 at the end of the echo commands or if it is completely useless. 3) I want it to go to email or to a Slack notification (post to an http hook url), but I want that message to be relatively brief and to the point. I think it would take too much code trying to handle every error scenario. I hope this makes sense.

@Barmar Good point with the disk being too full. I suppose ANY echo command with a redirect could fail. If I suppose I should check if that particular partition is close to being full at the beginning. That said, a redirect could be a to a network-mapped drive that occasionally fails, so it's not like I can handle every possible error condition.

Is there a reason why checking $? after the echo isn't sufficient?

echo is absolutely not a "trusted primitive building block".  echo "$x" doesn't work in general, and can fail in multiple ways.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to Why is printf better than echo?.


Does the echo command in Bash shell ever write anything to stderr without an explicit redirect of the output?

Yes. Proof by example:
#!/bin/bash
exec >&-
echo hello
/bin/echo world

Result showing both Bash builtin echo and GNU external echo writing to stderr:
foo: line 3: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
/bin/echo: write error: Bad file descriptor

Similar effects and situations can be achieved through broken pipes, full disks, and disconnected terminals.

But really, adding >> log 2>&1 to every command is an antipattern. Whatever invokes the script should be responsible for redirecting any output to a log file.

Thanks. Where did the sub-string foo come from and why exactly did the script that you listed fail?

foo was what I called the script file on my system. The script fails because stdout was closed before echo ran. Here it was closed by the script itself to be self contained, but it doesn't necessarily need to happen in the script

Is the - (dash) after >& on line 2 of the script significant? What exactly closes stdout before echo had a chance to run?

exec >&- means "close stdout in the current shell process". It's the same A>&B syntax as 2>&1, but "A" is not specified (default 1), and B is "-" meaning "close instead of copying the given FD".

Permission denied is written by bash as it attempts to open the file you wanted to redirect output to for writing. You'll never get rid of those errors by redirecting the output of echo itself.
If you want stderr to go somewhere other than where it's already going, you'll have to tell it go somewhere else at some point. There are several ways to do that without repeating 2>&1 over and over though. Some options:
You can execute the program with redirected outputs.
# Execute program with outputs redirected - will apply to any command
# within the script that doesn't explicitly override
bash myscript >/some/log/file 2>&1

You can change the output destination for the entire program after starting the script with exec:
# Use exec to change stdout and stderr
exec >/some/log/file 2>&1
echo foo >/file/with/permissions # writes "foo" to /file/with/permissions
echo bar >/file/without/permissions # writes Permission Denied to /some/log/file

You can change stderr for a set of commands by putting them in a group:
# write the stderr for some set of commands to a file
{
  echo foo >/file/with/permissions
  echo bar >/file/without/permissions
} >/some/log/file 2>&1

# also works for a function
write_stuff() {
  echo foo >/file/with/permissions
  echo bar >/file/without/permissions
}
write_stuff >/some/log/file 2>&1

# also works for subshells
(
  echo foo >/file/with/permissions
  echo bar >/file/without/permissions
) >/some/log/file 2>&1

